# Wix sitemap for http and https

Tags: google-search-console, https, sitemap

I have a website hosted in Wix and as you may know it automatically keeps a sitemap there (sitemap.xml).

Now that I activated https to my site, I read I should add another property on Google Search Console for the https address.

The thing is that both properties on Search Console (http and https) points to the only sitemap version Wix provides. If you look at it all URLs are https.

So now I have a http property containing a sitemap with https urls?

Is this normal? How does Search console deal with that?

Comment: I do not know Wix. However, in most situations, the HTTP version of a site would be redirected to HTTPS. This solves a whole host of problems including yours. See if there is an option in Wix.

Comment: It seems to do such redirect. My concern is that I will have a website property on google search console for http where its corresponding sitemap is https. Is this an issue? What I am seeing is a drop on the indexed number of pages in both properties.

Comment: No. You should be fine. You will see a drop in indexing for your HTTP property and an increase for your HTTPS property. That is normal and how it works.

Comment: Now I see that my previous 56 indexed URLs are split into HTTP and HTTPs properties. For me there should be no problem if it weren't for the drop on the daily visits. Lets wait a few more days to see what happens.

Comment: Changing to HTTPS is always a disruption. It is unavoidable. It will take more than a few days. Just be patient. It will all work out okay.

Comment: Just to keep you updated, now I have most of my traffic going to HTTPS and the indexed pages are slowly increasing, almost reaching the day I made the change to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Google's John Mueller says in [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox), one thing that Google uses your sitemaps for is dermining which URLs are canonical.   If a URL is listed in a sitemap, Google will prefer that URL over others with duplicate content.

That means that your sitemaps only containing HTTPS URLs is a a good thing.   It will mean that Google will prefer to index the HTTPS version of your website.   There are slight ranking benefits for HTTPS and it is much better for users from a security standpoint.